# Customize CardActionArea hover effect

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the material-ui's `CardActionArea` hover effect for one of the components in a React app I'm currently working on, but I can't seem to find any clear enough documentation about the styling needed.

I already tried injecting some inline styling with the "classes" prop, but I could see no effect whatsoever.

How could I implement this in a nice and clean way in my ( class-based ) component?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: LOL. My question is everything but broad or opinion-based, I'm sorry. I'm simply asking how to inject custom styling -via props- inside a material-ui's core component inside a React app.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Material UI docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Link: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed answer, but this is simply how to set custom styling for material-ui's components. What I'm looking for specifically is how to customize the hover effect for "CardActionArea" components.